# Why can't I add custom NSButtonCell to NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm attempting to create a custom view that contains a play/pause button, and I'll attach any number of these to an NSWindow. I started by creating my own NSView and just drawing out the various pieces, then subclassing the play/pause button as an NSView (baby steps).

This all worked fine until I decided my button needed to extend NSButtonCell rather than an NSView. The following (from TimeSlipView.m) fails miserably, and I can't seem to figure out why:

```
playPauseButton = [[TimeSlipViewButton alloc] init];
[playPauseButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
[self addSubview:playPauseButton];
```

I get a compile error and this warning for that last line: "Incompatible pointer types sending 'TimeSlipViewButton *__strong' to paremeter of type 'NSView *'".

I have a feeling I've misunderstood something very basic, and that for some reason I can't just pass `addSubview:` my NSButtonCell from within an NSView.

TimeSlipView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TimeSlipViewButton.h"

@interface TimeSlipView : NSView {
    TimeSlipViewButton *playPauseButton;
    NSView *timerText;
    NSView *clientText;
    NSView *projectText;
    NSView *taskText;
}

@end
```

TimeSlipViewButton.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TimeSlipViewButton : NSButtonCell

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cell Is no View and thus cannot be used as such! *what you do doesn't work*
You try exactly that when adding it as a subview

Cells are a (legacy) concept where views were too expensive.

The were/are used by some controls (like NSButton) to handle the actually drawing.

---

the Button CONTAINS a button cell
It ISNT a button cell, it IS a NSView

---

what you might wanna do is give a stock NSButton a specific ButtonCell that has custom drawing options. There are good tutorials out there for given existing NSButtons/NSSegmentedCells/NSTextFields custom NSCells

Comment: a cell is never added to the view hierarchy. when the nsview that owns the cell is asked to draw it DELEGATES this on to the cell explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, Daij-Djan. I understand now that I'm misusing the NSButtonCell by design, and that I neglected to pay attention to its inheritance. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry If sound harsh - bad mood :D -- anyway if you have concrete problem with cells (I dislike their existence) just ask :D

Comment: Not harsh at all! This is a bit of a RTFM situation, anyway. Thank you sir.